# Zing Charts - Place Items on Map

Tags: maps, zingchart

I am trying to put Location markers on an USA map similar to the one in this page

http://www.zingchart.com/blog/2012/07/17/interactive-html5-maps-api/
(Place items on map section.)

I am not able to find the JSON attribute for specifying this (The link on it is taking to the site's home page only).
Please help me on how to do this or point me to any documentation on it.

[--EDIT--]
I found a function to get the XY coordinates on the map using the Lat/Lon value and vice-versa (zingchart.maps.getXY(mapid, lonlat, itemid)).. But I am still stuck with placing a marker on that XY point.

[--EDIT--]
Below answers work as expected. I am trying to put markers on US map. I would like to know how to place markers on Alaska/ Hawaii states with lat/lon info since they are placed below california as a separate polygon though they are geographically above the US.

Comment: Balaprasanna, you found maps info in a blog post from 2012. In addition to the answer below, a more up to date maps article can be found in the ZingChart docs at http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/maps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the ZingChart team, and I can definitely help you out with this!

It's critical that you wait until the map has loaded before finding the XY coordinates. Use the ZingChart 'load' API event listener to wait until the chart has loaded:

```
zingchart.load=function() {
    drawPoints();
};
```

Inside our drawPoints function, we'll find the longitude and latitude values. If the values are north and east, the numbers will be positive, south and west will be negative. For example, Sao Paulo is located at 46.6333° W, 23.5500° S, so we would use [-46.63, -23.55]. In [this map demo](http://zingchart.com/playground/run/54077e9d8cd24), we've placed a marker at Bangalore, which is located at 77.5667° E, 12.9667° N, so we'll use [77.57, 12.97].

```
var lonlat = [77.57, 12.97];
var bangalore = zingchart.maps.getXY('map', lonlat);
```

The getXY method returns an array of length 2, with the value at index 0 being the x position and the value at index 1 being the y position for your map.

Now that we have the X Y coordinates for Bangalore in our variable, we can use the [addobject API method](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__addobject) to place a marker at that location. Below, 'zc' is the same as the id given to the div used to place the chart.

```
zingchart.exec('zc', 'addobject', {
    type: 'shape',
    data: [{
        x: bangalore[0],
        y: bangalore[1],
        type: "circle",
        size: 3
    }]
});
```

To see the code in its entirety, view the page source of the map demo provided.

Please let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Thanks! I am able to do it now. One more question.. Is it possible to add an image object (similar to shape) or set a background image to that shape?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Check out [this demo](http://zingchart.com/playground/run/5408b5c0c265d). I've made a few simple changes to the addobject method. I changed the shape type to square, changed the size of the shape, added the background-image attribute (which points to the marker image on our server), the background-repeat:no-repeat attribute, and added offsets to the x and y attributes to ensure that the marker accurately points to Bangalore. It's also worth noting that I changed the render output in my render method to 'canvas' because SVG does not support the background-repeat attribute.

Comment: Thanks! It works great.. I also noticed that a constant being added to the XY point. In this case, "x" : bangalore[0]+5 &     "y" : bangalore[1]-13. How is this determined? I am placing markers on a US map & I have to drill down into the states as well in the future. Can that same constant needs to be added or would I have to compute it differently?

Comment: Those offsets depend on the size of the shape object as well as the size of your marker image that you'll be using. In this case, I had to manually adjust the position so that the point of my marker lined up with Bangalore. Once you find the appropriate offset for your marker, you should be able to use the same values without much issue :)